# With Google Chrome web apps, is there any way to make Flash a prerequisite?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've created a google chrome web app, and got it functioning just fine on multiple different setups. The only issue is for the user to get it to work they must go into their chrome://plugins page and enable flash. Is there any way to automatically do this or ask for permission to do so? I've looked through the manifest.json template guide and the only thing in there about requirements is the "requirements" tag which is specific to napi and webgl. Besides just saying Flash is required in the description, do I have any other options?

Comment: Why do you need Flash?

Comment: Daniel Herr I developed a game in flash using haxeflixel and was trying to avoid the pain of adapting all the js myself for non locally hosted web pages

Answer (score 0):

The Netscape Plug-in Application Programming Interface (NPAPI) that allows plug-ins to be developed for web browsers is being phased out.

As noted in [NPAPI deprecation: developer guide](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/npapi-deprecation?pli=1):

> In September 2015 (Chrome 45) we will remove the override and NPAPI support will be permanently removed from Chrome. Installed extensions that require NPAPI plugins will no longer be able to load those plugins.

Alternatives to NPAPI can be found in the documentation.